# Angular multi selector autocomplete .

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, multi-select

I want to use angular multi selector autocomplete below is my working demo only for select one item. **Html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <p></p>
    <b>Selected User</b>
    
    Enter a name: <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="user as (user.first + ' ' + user.last) for user in users | filter:$viewValue" />
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my **js**

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.selected = "";
  $scope.users = [
    {'id': 1, 'first': 'John', 'last': 'Depp', 'age':52, 'gender':'male'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'first': 'Sally', 'last': 'JoHanson', 'age':13, 'gender':'female'},
    {'id': 3, 'first': 'Taylor', 'last': 'Swift', 'age':22, 'gender':'female'},
    {'id': 4, 'first': 'Max', 'last': 'Payne', 'age':72, 'gender':'male'},
    {'id': 5, 'first': 'Jessica', 'last': 'Hutton', 'age':12, 'gender':'female'},
    {'id': 6, 'first': 'Nicholas', 'last': 'Cage','age':3, 'gender':'male'},
    {'id': 7, 'first': 'Lisa', 'last': 'Simpson', 'age':18, 'gender':'female'}
  ];

}
```

Can i do that with out **typeahead** ? Also want to select multiple value from drop down please help me.

Comment: Angular Material has an autocomplete control and a select control with multi-select option. https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.9/demo/autocomplete

However, I haven't found how to do both, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Mutiselect in ui-select might do the job for you

```
 <ui-select multiple class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selected" name="name" >
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or Search">{{$item.first}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="val.first as val in vm.values | filter: $select.search">
       {{val.first}}
       <div ng-bind-html="val | highlight: $select"></div>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

This link will give you a rough idea [Multi select](http://jsfiddle.net/vignesh230794/Lv9mo66a/619/)